# saving a document in the word 2003 format

Tags: phpword

http://phpword.codeplex.com/documentation includes an example of how to save in the Word 2007 docx format:

```
$objWriter = PHPWord_IOFactory::createWriter($PHPWord, 'Word2007');
$objWriter->save('helloWorld.docx');
```

Is it possible to save a document in the Word 2003 format instead? If not are there other libraries that might?

Comment: Having a quick look on their Forum, it looks like nobody who asked this same question got a reply. Just this one: http://phpword.codeplex.com/discussions/225616

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project has been transfered to Github : https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/. Actually, [reading a file Word 97-2003](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/issues/23) is in the pipe. So we will implement Word97 writing feature, after that.

Else :

- You can [write RTF/DOCX Files](http://phpword.readthedocs.org/en/develop/intro.html#file-formats) with PHPWord read by Word97 ([with Addin for DOCX](http://www.clubic.com/telecharger-fiche31748-add-in-odf-pour-microsoft-word.html))
- You can [write RTF Files with PHPRtfLite](https://github.com/phprtflite/PHPRtfLite) read by Word97
- You can write Word97 with the PHP extension COM : [Sample](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/class.com.php#class.com.examples) (only for Windows and if you have installed Office)

Comment: The COM extension only works if you're on Windows and have Office actually installed FWIW

Comment: COM extension is so bad solution that you can remove it or at least put it in the last position.